# Discrete subspace of a Hausdorff space

Tags: general-topology

Every  infinite Hausdorff space  has  a countably  infinite discrete  subspace.

Now  I  know $R$  under  usual  topology  has $Z$  and under  "lower  limit  topology"  also  has $Z$  as such. So goes  on for  $R^{n}$ as  long  as  $n$  is  finite it  will  be  $Z^{n}$ .But  what  about general  Hausdorff  Spaces?  Please  some  hints.

I  need  to  know what  such  discrete  subspaces  might  look  like  for $R^{inf}$ since $Z^{\inf}$  or $N^{\inf}$ are  not  countable.

Comment: The  other  link  was  helpful. It has  the  proof  but I  also need   the  answer  for  $R^{\inf }$  which  is  not  asked  there.  So please  someone  kindly give  some  hints about the  countably  infinite  discrete subspace  of $R^{\inf}$.